# CryptographicException when loading certificate for client side TLS authentication

Tags: iis, x509certificate, client-certificates, x509certificate2

While attempting a https request from our web application (which runs on IIS, using .NET Framework 4.6.1) with TLS client certificate based authentication, we get the following error when loading the client certificate:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils.LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
```

This happens both when loading it from file and loading it from byte array. I already tried to import the p12 file in the local machine certificate, and granting rights to the app pool user on which the web app is running, but this did not fix the issue.

The server runs on Windows Server 2012 R2 and uses active directory for user management. The web app is running on the builtin ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: Shot in the dark: You're running without loading a user profile.

Comment: Could you get it work by setting application pool identity to local system?